# c++, infinite loop, sockets, Tic Tac Toe Program

Tags: c++, sockets

I want to establish a socket communication between a Client and a Server.
I am trying to use an infinite loop to make the communication. 
I show a minimal expression of the loop.
This loop is the one for the Client. The server is going to have a similar code with the difference in the value of turno.
While Client has turno=1, Servidor has turno=2.

```
while(true) 
{
    if(turno==1)
    {   
       //Ingreso de datos
        string input; 
        getline(cin, input); 
        if (input.size() > BUFFER_LEN )
        {
            input = input.substr(0,BUFFER_LEN);
        }

        cout<<turno<<endl;

        cout<<"Escribo:" <<input<<endl;
        turno=2;


    }
    else if(turno==2)

    {

        cout<<"HO"<<endl;
        string buffer = clientSocket.Receive(); 

        cout<<"LA"<<endl;
        turno=1;
    }

}
```

My goal with the loop was to make that both programs (client.cpp and servidor.cpp) run at the same time. I mean while the client is sending information, the servidor is receiving that information. And while the servidor is sending information, the client is receiving information.
But I don't see that happening in the terminal.
Instead, in the client terminal I get this photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCJax.png). 
And, when I close the terminal of the client, I get this in the terminal of the server [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4Dot.png)
I suspect that the program stops at the `string buffer=clientSocket.Receive();` , maybe because this command is waiting for some information (from the server) that didn't arrive. Meaning that both programs are not running at the same time.
I also upload the code for making the transmission of the message.
The following code is for receiving information. This comes from a class that I made to make the socket.

```
string socket_::Receive(void){
    string buffer;
    recv(client_descriptor, (char*)buffer.c_str(), BUFFER_LEN, 0);
    cout<<"Mensaje Recibido"<<endl;
    return buffer;};
```

I suspect that it would be a great idea to add the code of the socket_ class.

```
#define MSG_OPEN_SOCKET_ERROR "Error al iniciar el socket"
#define MSG_BIND_ERROR "Error al mapear el socket con la dirección     local "
#define MSG_ACCEPT_ERROR "Error al establecer conexion con el  oponente."
#define MSG_WAIT_CONNECT "Esperando al oponente..."
#define MSG_CONNECT_SUCCESS "Conexion exitosa, comienza el juego!"
#define MSG_CONNECT_ERROR "Error al conectar con el servidor."
#define MSG_SOCKET_CLOSE "Conexion finalizada exitosamente, hasta luego!"


/* Constructor por default */
socket_::socket_(){
 domain = AF_INET;
 type = SOCK_STREAM;
 protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
 server_descriptor = 0;
 client_descriptor = 0; 
}

/* Inicio de socket servidor */
bool socket_::StartServer(char *port){

/* Configuro el socket del servidor */
sockaddr_in serverAddress;
bzero((char*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));    /* Inicializo    con ceros el socket */
serverAddress.sin_family = domain;                      /* Protocolo IPv4 */
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);      /* Guardo las ip de todas las interfaces */
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));         /* Guardo el puerto ingresado */

/* Abro el socket en modo IPv4 - TCP */
server_descriptor = socket(domain, type, protocol);
if(server_descriptor == FLAG_OPEN_SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << MSG_OPEN_SOCKET_ERROR
        << endl;
    return false;
}   

/* Mapeo el socket con las ip locales */
int bindStatus = bind(server_descriptor, (struct sockaddr*) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
if(bindStatus == FLAG_BIND_ERROR)
{
    cout << MSG_BIND_ERROR
        << serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr
        << ":"
        << serverAddress.sin_port
        << endl;
    return false;
}

/* Escucho a la espera de conexiones entrantes, máximo 1 */
cout << MSG_WAIT_CONNECT
    << endl;
listen(server_descriptor, LISTEN_MAXCONN);    

/* Acepto conexion entrante */
sockaddr_in clientAddress;
socklen_t clientAddressLenght = sizeof(clientAddress);
client_descriptor = accept(server_descriptor, (sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &clientAddressLenght);
 if(client_descriptor == FLAG_ACCEPT_ERROR)
 {
     cout << MSG_ACCEPT_ERROR
        << endl;
     return false;
 }

 return true;
```

};

```
/* Inicio de socket cliente */
bool socket_::StartClient(char * ip, char *port){

/* Configuro los parametros del servidor */
struct hostent* host = gethostbyname(ip);  /* Si se ingreso un hostname, solicito su ip por ARP y la guardo en el formato requerido */
sockaddr_in serverAddress;
bzero((char*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)); 
serverAddress.sin_family = domain;                                                          /* Protocolo IPv4 */
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)*host->h_addr_list));     /* Guardo la IP destino ingresada */
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));                                                 /* Guardo el puerto destino ingresado */

/* Creo el socket en modo TCP */
client_descriptor = socket(domain, type, protocol);

/* Intento conectar contra el servidor */
int status = connect(client_descriptor, (sockaddr*) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
if(status < FLAG_CONNECT_ERROR)
{
    cout << MSG_CONNECT_ERROR
        << endl;
    return false;
}
   cout << MSG_CONNECT_SUCCESS
     << endl;

  return true;

};
```

Comment: `buffer`  needs to have at least `BUFFER_LEN` characters, you're not allowed to write through `c_str()`, and `recv` doesn't necessarily receive all the characters at once.

Comment: Unrelated: do NOT ignore the return code from `recv`. It contains vital information.

Comment: Recommend adding what kind of protocol you're using to the question. Most likely you are using TCP or UDP, and this clears up a lot of ambiguity. If you're using something unusual, we definitely need this information.

Comment: It seems likely that you simply have both client and server waiting to receive data at the same time. However, from what you've provided here, there's insufficient information for anyone to help you. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am using TCP. Should I also post the code where I establish the server/client communication?

Comment: Best bet is to manufacture a [mre], and if that doesn't have you giving yourself a slap and then fixing the bug, add the MRE to the question.